# How to find max new ISODate from MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a requirement that, I want to select max date from MongoDB using Query;

This is what I tried:

```
db.getCollection('rrr.backup').find({$max:'insTime'});
```

Getting the following error

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $max",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Can anyone suggest me that, how to get the result with $max operator

Comment: You can use `$max` operator with only `$group` and `$project` stage not with the find query... Instead use `sort` with `limit`... Something like this `db.getCollection('rrr.backup').find({}).sort({ insTime: -1 }).limit(1)`

Comment: Is there anyway that, I can access directly with $max?

Comment: Please have a look at duplicate answer